# NGINX in front of TOMCAT to serve static files

Tags: macos, tomcat, grails, nginx

I'm working on a project with `grails 2.2.2` on a local machine `Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5` I have installed `NGINX` with `brew` and modified the `nginx.conf` as following :

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

    root /;

    access_log /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/logs/myproject_access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }

    #images folders
    location /posters {
        root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/posters/;   
    }

    #images folders
    location /avatars {
        root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/avatars/;
    }

    #images folders
    location /waveforms {
        root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/waveforms/;     
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

When I access `http://localhost:8081` my site is running but I want to be sure the `images` are served by `nginx` and not by `tomcat` so I look at `myproject_access.log` but nothing is happening.

`ngnix` is writing into the log **ONLY** when `tomcat` is **NOT** running.

Is there a way to "monitor" the static files served by `nginx` ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
Executing curl -I http://localhost:8081
```

when tomcat is running the output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1    //TOMCAT
...
```

when tomcat is NOT running the output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.4.1   //NGINX
Date: Tue, 08 Apr 2014 09:30:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your are making the both servers listen on the same port, you need to move tomcat to another port like `8082` and let nginx listen to the main port ( which is `8081` in your case ), and then tell nginx to proxy to `8082` when the request isn't an image ( or any asset ).

also here's a refinement to your server block

```
server {
  server_name localhost;
  listen 8081;
  root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects;
  location @tomcat {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @tomcat;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying your solution but still don't understand perfectly what is going on.. On my browser should I use http://localhost:8081 or 8082 ? Sorry if it's a stupid question but Im a bit lost.. I still don't know how to see if the static files are served by nginx or tomcat

Comment: 8082 would be the tomcat server, and 8081 would be the nginx server, you would write the 8081 normally as you do now, and the server would decide if it's a request for something that can be passed right away like images or css files or js files, if not nginx then would pass the request to tomcat and wait for tomcat to reply and the pass the reply to the user

Comment: 8081 is pointing to nginx and 8082 to tomcat,
with 8082 it is working but with 8081 I get error 500.

Comment: if you can give me the error from the errors log it would be helpful

Comment: also try `sudo nginx -t` and paste me the output if it's an error

Comment: ngnix -t

'nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [warn] 1024 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 256
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful'

Comment: yea seems the config is fine, check `/var/log/nginx` and paste me the error you get when u refresh `localhost:8081`

Comment: when I do 'curl -I http://localhost:8082' or 'curl -I http://localhost:8081'  I get the same response 'Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1'

Comment: well if 8082 is the same as 8081, then that means that nginx is proxying correctly, did the error 500 stop happening?

Comment: my site is now working with both 8081 and 8082 but the http headers still show 'Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1'

Comment: Yes no error but nginx is not writing in the access log when I do an http request and still  'Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1' in the headers. Is  this normal ? or yould I see nginx in the servers headers ?

Comment: Is there a way to be sure that it is nginx that is serving my images ?

Comment: check the response headers, if tomcat is adding a response header it won't exist in the images served by nginx